# Search with Parameters from Two MVC Models with a Many-To-Many Relationship

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to return a set of Vendor entities from a search that uses a company name from the Vendor model, and a category name from the Category model as parameters. The client could choose to use either search parameter, or both at the same time.

What I want to do is set up a **List<Vendor>** that is a result of searching the Vendors model against the Vendor *Company* property and then searching again against the Category *CategoryName* property.

The Vendor and Category models have a many-to-many relationship.

These are the models:

```
public class public class Vendor
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Company { get; set; }       
    ...
    [Required]
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Vendor> Vendors { get; set; }
}
```

The HTML code is:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
{    
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        Vendor Name: @Html.TextBox("Search")
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            Vendor Category: @Html.DropDownList("VendorCategory", "All")
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Search" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

The part of the Controller method that handles the search is:

```
public ActionResult Index(string Search, int? VendorCategory)
{
    var vendors = from v in db.Vendors select v;

    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Search))
    {
        vendors = vendors.Where(s => s.Company.Contains(Search));
    }

    //Filter the remaining vendors based on the Vendor CategoryName returned from the dropdown list.
    if(VendorCategory != null)
    {   
         //Get the category ID of the Category name selected on the home page Vendor Category dropdown list. 
         int TheCategoryID = VendorCategory.GetValueOrDefault();

         vendors = ???
    }    
}
```

I'm stuck at the last code line of how to create a LINQ query to return only the Vendors that have the CategoryID of the Category name string returned from the drop-down list. I know the navigation property references a set of Category objects, and I'm not sure how to write a LINQ query that gets all remaining Vendors with a Category object reference with the Category ID in question.

I'm new to MVC/Entity Framework, and don't have an extensive knowledge of LINQ (not sure about the Category cast on the query assigning the result to the TheCategory variable), so I understand I may be going about this all wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `Vendor` has a collection of `Category`s, your `Vendor` query should be quite simple:

```
var vendors = Vendors.Where(v => v.Categories.Select(c => c.CategoryId)
                                             .Contains(TheCategoryID));
```

For each `Vendor v`, we transform the `Categories` list to `IEnumerable<int>` which represents all the IDs, then we search that for `TheCategoryID` to see if it's present. If so, it returns true and is included by the `Where` clause.

Comment: This worked perfectly. A note to those who may have viewed the ealier code, I edited the question since I made substantial changes to the controller code to handle the dropdownlist (index signature and getting the category ID), but I still used the LINQ query provided by Daniel for the last line in the above controller code.